# Composition of infinite comparison functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, control-theory, stability-theory

A $\mathcal{K}$ function $\alpha: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ obeys $\alpha(0) = 0$ and $\alpha(a) > \alpha(b)$ for $a > b$. An identity function $\mathrm{id}: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ obeys $\mathrm{id}(s) = s$.

Suppose we have some $\mathcal{K}$ function $\alpha < \mathrm{id}$, i.e., $\alpha(s) < \mathrm{id}(s)$ for all $s > 0$. Given an $s \in \mathbb{R}_+$, do we have $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\underbrace{\alpha\circ\alpha\circ \cdots \circ \alpha}_{k}(s) = 0$ (here $\circ$ denotes composition of functions)?

My intuition is that the above claim may not be true, and the answer could be $s - c$ with any constant $c < s$. But I have no idea how to proceed the proof, and I can not come up with some example.

Comment: How you define the limit of composition of functions here?

Comment: @KBS For example, if $\alpha(s) = \frac{1}{2}s$, then $\alpha\circ\alpha(s) = \frac{1}{4}s$, and $\alpha\circ\alpha(s)\circ\alpha(s) = \frac{1}{8}s$.

Comment: Yeah but one needs to consider convergence and what does it mean to have a limit of such functions to be equal to zero. For instance, the limit may not be a function at all.

Comment: @KBS There is a condition: "Given an $s \in \mathbb{R}_+$", so the limit should be a real number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The infinite composition of functions is equivalent to the discrete time system

$$
s_{k+1}=\alpha(s_k)
$$

, $\mathcal{K}$-function $\alpha$ and $\alpha(s)<\text{id}(s), s>0$. So you are practically asking if this discrete system (with unique equilbrium at $0$) is asymptotically stable for all $s_0 \in \mathbb{R}_+$.

Since we consider non-negative $s$, use the Lyapunov function $V(s)=s$.

Then $V(s_{k+1})-V(s_k)=\alpha(s_k)-s_k=\alpha(s_k)-\text{id}(s_k)<0$ for $s_k>0$ so your limit should always converge to zero.

Comment: In principle, you need more than that because problems may occur if $|s(x)-x|$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity. You would need rather $V(\alpha(s))-V(s)\le-\beta(s)$ for some continuous positive definite function $\beta$.

Comment: @KBS Um no, this is literally just the discrete time version of Lyapunov stability which says that if $V(s_{k+1})-V(s_k)<0$ then the equilibrium is asymptotically stable.

Comment: Not in the nonlinear case. In the linear case, what you say implies what I am saying, but not in the nonlinear case. This is the same in the continuous-time setting. There is an underlying reason for using $\mathcal{K}$-type functions.

Comment: @KBS No? The whole point of Lyapunov function theory is to deal with nonlinear systems. In the continuous-time setting it is also sufficent to show $\dot{V}(s)<0$ in order to show asymptotic stability. No $\beta$ there.

Comment: No, the derivative needs to be bounded away from 0. The issue with the strict inequality is that when $t\to\infty$, the derivative tends to zero. The same issue may appear in the discrete-time setting. Take for instance the system $\dot{x}(t)=-1/(1+t^2)x(t)$, we have that $\dot{V}<0$, yet we do not not converge to 0. Often, the symbol $<$ is interpreted as "strongly negative definite" and one can see that the above derivative is not strongly negative definite.

Comment: @KBS No, you are mixing now autonomous and non-autonomous systems which is not valid. What you say is only true for non-autonomous systems. The system is question is clearly autonomous (as $\alpha$ depends only on the state variable), so theory for autonomous systems applies. Please take a look for example at this [technical report](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.05289.pdf) on "Lyapunov Theory for Discrete Time Systems", the definitions are very clear.

Comment: Yeah that's correct, I was confused with a result with guaranteed convergence rate, which is arbitrarily slow here.